# How to show 2nd Form under 1st form's menu bar on application startup?

Tags: c#, winforms

Output should like --> Snapshot:
[SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d11N.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate who is the parent form to be able to contain the second form within the first one. For example:

```c#
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
Form Form2 = new Form();
Form2.MdiParent = this;
Form2.Show();
```